# Different results are obtained with "order by" used in both queries with and without the filtering condition

Tags: dolphindb, mismatch, stockquotes

I want to calculate a specific subset of data from the 1-minute data source in table *M_1*. Here are my scripts:

```
one=select code,dates, iif(deltas(J)>0,1,0) as J_up from (select * , MACD(close, 5, 34, 5) as `DIF`DEA`MACD`J from M_1 where code="000001" order by code,dates)

all=select code,dates, iif(deltas(J)>0,1,0) as J_up from (select * , MACD(close, 5, 34, 5) as `DIF`DEA`MACD`J from M_1 order by code,dates)
```

Using the `order by` clause, I performed two kinds of queries: one retrieves all data and the other filters the data by the stock ID "000001". But the results are different:

[image]

I don’t understand why is that. Does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause lies in that the `select` statement is executed before the `order by` clause. The subqueries perform calculations on the data before it is sorted by “code“ and “dates“. Since the `MACD` function involves sequence-dependent calculations, the order of the rows differs if the query range is different, which will affect the final results. To fix your problem, first sort the *M_1* by “code” and “dates” before executing the `MACD`.